# Has anyone kept a copy of LamsTeX version 1?

Tags: incompatibility, format-files

I wrote my PhD thesis (back in spring 1990) in LamsTeX version 1 (version 2 came out in 1991). I would like to recompile my thesis manuscript but on CTAN only version 2.01 is available (and I noticed very quickly that there seem to be a lot of undocumented changes between v1 and v2). Has anyone kept a copy of that package version?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way is to contact its maintainer, Michael Spivak?

Comment: I don't think that LamsTeX version 1 has ever been publicly released. It used to be paid software. Some years after version 2 was released, it was put on CTAN for free (the manual still was sold).

Comment: Any idea on how I can contact Michael Spivak?

Comment: @yannis -- search on the net for "publish or perish press spivak".  i believe the email address given there is still effective.